# how to fix Warning message of; package.json contains a custom build that is being ignored. after using 'firebase deploy'?

Tags: firebase, next.js, uuid

[image] **"WARNING: your package.json contains a custom build that is being ignored. Only the Next.Js default build script (e.g, "next build") is respected. If you have a more advanced custom integration [https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/express"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/express%22)**

i have an clue that with with while trying to use "npm install -g firebase-tools" earlier in the firebase integration on my project, i got warnings of those two npm warns, that could be a reason for getting the warning after 'firebase deploy' that along with it bring the new super vague error.

**"Error: an unexpected error has ocurred."**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**what should i use instead of these 'har-validator' and 'uuid'?cause it seem that they are very deprecated, and by fixing it with an replacement could fix this error.**

-i have searched and asked people about what should i use in the place of those two 'uuid' and 'har-validator' but i didnt find a single thing.

those things are the only things i have to look for to try fixing this problem, i have searched and some people got a close issue, not totally the same issue, but some said to run the command using CMD with admin, some closed the localhost of the project and ran the command with Git bash inside the project cause the localhost gave conflicts problems, and some deleted node modules and reinstalled them, i have tried all of those, including deleting the whole project two times and redoing all of the installations again keeping an close eye to the paths i was installing everything, so i do also know that its nothing related to a root problem.

in the project i used a complete custom layout interface from figma with Locofy plugin, i have checked every file and folder to see if it could be something that wasnt in the package.json for some reason, giving the conflict.

nexjs build:

npx create-next-app@latest
what options i used:
javascript,
,Eslint
,Tailwind CSS
,No src/ directory
,No  App Router
,No  import alias

[image]

after creating the project i did all the changes with the styles and my own build from figma with locofy and ran 'npm run dev' and everything worked fine.

before the firebase installation i used '`npm run build`' to make the project ready to deploy, and then did the basic firebase installation:

`npm install -g firebase-tools`
`firebase experiments:enable webframeworks`
`firebase init hosting`
`firebase deploy`

which is where i get the 'Warning custom build that is being ignored' problem